# How can I make a simple circuit to output only after a min input voltage is exceeded?

Tags: diodes, zener, basic

Here's my problem....

I am setting up a camera system on a motor coach that is designed to trigger separate cameras when blinkers or backup is engaged.

the problem I'm having is the only accessible trigger voltage line I have goes from 10v when blinker is off up to 24v when blinkers are engaged. The problem is the 10v on the line is engaging my triggers...i need it to be zero until I turn on the blinker and allow the 24v to activate the triggers

So I thought I could build e a simple zener diode circuit to achieve this.... I purchased a 18v zener and some 2k resisters.... but it's been about 15 years since I've been in electronics and I've forgotten how to get the correct values or parts to achieve my goal and how to build a working circuit.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it... my idea worked but when the zener turned on I only output 3v on the backside (anode) of the zener.

Thank you for any advice...

---

**Update:**

I actually posted a picture of the circuit I made which actually worked great for me but apparently it didn't show up here.

I did confirm a solid 10v with a DVM when switch is off.
The motor coach runs on 24v  - some systems run by 12v and others 24.
I'm suspect of the 10v being present too because we have a generator being installed and the installer put switches in so you can toggle from Gen power to bus power.  I think he may have hooked up something wrong... but for now this fix works

The circuit which Russel posted (small circuit on left) is almost identical to what I had. except i used 2 zeners (one 11v and the other 13v) one regular diode, a coupling capacitor and a 75 ohm resistor.

Comment: If the problem is to remove (subtract) 10 V, really a backward connected Zener diode, in series to a resistor or the load, will work. Ensure the minimum current required.

Comment: Thank you for responding...

Comment: Thank you for responding...the problem I'm having is trying to remove the 10v on the line until I turn on the blinker switch... which then goes up to 24v. So I need at least 10-24v for my device to trigger that individual camera.  so having 10v on the line when the blinker is off is triggering my camera all the time. so I'm trying to have it read zero until I turn on the blinker.  hope that makes since..

Comment: @DTBeasley - I'm not an auto electrician, but that *apparent* 10V "blinkers off" voltage is suspicious IMHO. I have a guess what might be happening, but just to be clear: (a) How did you measure that 10V - using a DMM on its DC voltage range or something else? (b) How do you know that it is a *constant* 10V? Did you use anything like a scope to measure it? (c) Is it a 24V electrical system on that vehicle? (d) Did you get any advice from an experienced auto-electrician already? (e) Does that vehicle have "bulb blown" warning capability, or does it pre-date that technology?

Comment: I think I figured it out now.  My output is zero until I turn on the signal then it goes to 12.3v....

Comment: @DTBeasley - "*My output is zero until I turn on the signal then it goes to 12.3v....*" It's not clear what you mean by "my output". If you mean "*the only accessible trigger voltage line*" mentioned in the question, then switching between zero and 12.3V is totally different to the situation described in the question (where the whole problem was that it *didn't* drop to zero). I'm now confused about what situation you are trying to solve - the one in the question (where I asked for extra details), or the one where something already switches between zero and 12.3V, which you wanted anyway! :-(

Comment: It would be polite and very wise to update your question if you have solved it somehow yourself - tell us what you did or found or how what you described did not match what you had. Wandering off without telling people who tried to help discourages others in future.

Comment: Absolutely....I actually posted (i thought I did) a picture of the circuit I made that worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two circuits which are potentially suitable.
A more complete knowledge of your situation is needed to design with certainty.

The left hand circuit outputs a voltage which is Vzener less than Vin.
C1 acts as a filter capacitor to provide DC when a blinker signal is the trigger.
R1 serves to provide a minimum load to the zener and to dissipate the capacitor energy when the source signal is removed.

The right hand circuit enables the transistor only when input voltages well in excess of 10V are present. As shown it tracks Vin when it is flashing. This could be changed if needs be. eg a capacitor on Q1_C or at Q1_b could be arranged to assist.

Q1 base drive voltage = Vin x R2/(R1 + r2) = Vin/28 with the components shown.
For Vin = 10V, Vbase = 10/28  = 0.36V
For Vin = 24V, Vbase = 24/28  = 0.86V.
The transistor needs ABOUT Vbase = 0.6V to operate.

D2 and C4 form a reservoir to operate the circuit from briefly if the input is pulsing and a steady on trigger voltage is required. If a steady output is not needed then D2 can be shorted and C4 omitted.

R4 discharges C2 when Vin is removed if the output load is not adequate to do so in reasonable time.

The circuits can be 'improved' if more information is provided on the requirement.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkaVxV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: you may need to increase R2 to 2K,

Comment: @Jasen No. Increasing R2 to 2K means that the voltage needed to turn on the transistor (about 0.6V Vbe) = (27+2)/2 x 0.6 = 8.7V -> = below the 10V must-be-off voltage originally posited by the OP.

Comment: with D2 in series with the emitter the base needs to be 1.2V below the supply to turn the transistor on, not 0.6.  you probably wat ot get rid of C2 also, the 24V is probably not well regulated and C2 increases the noise succeptability.

Comment: @Jasen Good point on D2. Comes of adding diode as afterthought probably, or lack of sleep, or other excuses :-). I'll move the R2/D2 junction, as the point - badly served as-is, is to keep Vout on when Vin pulses. C2 is a reservoir to tide over the Vin off periods - or wll be whem I move R2. Adding a finite load may also be wise, depending on the load.

Comment: Absolutely....sorry for the delay my phone was down.  I actually posted (i thought I did) a picture of the circuit I made which actually worked great for me but apparently it didn't show up here ..but to answer your questions...i did confirm a solid 10v with a DVM when switch is off. The motor coach runs on 24v ... some systems run by 12v and others 24. I'm suspect of the 10v being present too because we have a generator being installed and the installer put switches in so you can toggle from Gen power to bus power...i think he may have hooked up something wrong... but for now this fix works

Comment: you guys gave great input... thank you so much! I can't seem to upload the circuit but the one Mr.  Russel posted (small circuit on left) is almost identical to what I had. except i used 2 zeners (one 11v and the other 13v) one regular diode, a coupling capacitor and a 75 ohm resistor.